# Appending option tags to select tag from array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an options drop down list in html using JQuery to append from an Array.

Everything appears to be working correctly apart from the text between the opening & closing tags is not appearing.  Am I so tired i'm missing a simple typo or doing something wrong?!?

The JS and JQuery code is:

```
var displayMenuSelections = function(){
  var menuSelection = menu[0].prices[0];
  var menuItems = Object.keys(menuSelection);
  menuItems.forEach(menuFunction);
}

function menuFunction(item){
  $('#menu').append($('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option'));
}
```

The result of a typical option tag looks like this (with the 'item' missing between the opening and closing tags):

```
<option value="Cafe Latte"></option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `>` for the closing option tag. JQuery tries to close it for you, and in the process the inner item text doesn't get set.

Jquery takes a philosophy where it sort of tries to work with whatever you give it - this can be both good and bad, but in this case it makes it harder to debug since there's no error/exception that is raised.

```
var displayMenuSelections = function(){
  var menuSelection = menu[0].prices[0];
  var menuItems = Object.keys(menuSelection);
  menuItems.forEach(menuFunction);
}

function menuFunction(item){
  $('#menu').append($('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's late and I'm tired and I swear I checked it like 100 times and couldn't see anything missing!  My bad!

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you are not passing your parameter

```
item
```

to your function

```
menuFunction(item)
```

I'm just assuming you are trying to send

```
var menuSelection
```

so you can try changing your function call to

```
menuItems.forEach(menuFunction(menuSelection));
```

I have not tested this however!

Comment: This is not true. The javascript forEach method passes each element of the object on which it is called to the function.  So `menuItems.forEach(menuFunction)` would pass each element of the menuItems object to menuFunction.